# Error The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, reporting-services

When i run code with same credential with localhost it works properly but when i deploy it to server it is giving me the below error:

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

I have tried permission to report server for particular user report server url is working separately in server and localhost both with same credentials also tried `<identity impersonate="true"/>` but no luck, my code is below:

```
string UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsrsUserName"];
//added by nilesh
string Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsrsPassword"];
//added by nilesh
//   string ReportUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MileageReport"];
//added by nilesh
// string ReportServer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];

string folder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rptfolder"].ProviderName;
string reportURL = "";
reportURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rpturl"].ProviderName;

ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportURL);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = folder + "MileageReport";
//ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = folder + "testReport";
//added by nilesh
IReportServerCredentials irsc = new ReportCredentials(UserName, Password, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["domain"].ProviderName);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
// bool isauthenticated = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.ImpersonationUser.IsAuthenticated;
UserDataClass.LogError(userData.userId, "Not Error " + " UserName " + UserName + " Password " + Password + " Domain " +               System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["domain"].ProviderName + " ReportPath " + ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath + " reportURL " + ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl );
//                ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerNetworkCredentials();
ReportParameterInfoCollection pInfo = default(ReportParameterInfoCollection);
System.Collections.Generic.List<ReportParameter> paramList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ReportParameter>();
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("StartDate", startDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), false));
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("EndDate", endDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), false));
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("DeviceId", "ALL", false));
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("DQCustId", Convert.ToString(userData.customerId), false));
paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("UserId", Convert.ToString(userData.userId), false));
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
pInfo = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters();
//   ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Findings for Ssrs server configuration
Error The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
This error exactly means that if you are using correct credentials then report url is wrong it doesn’t returning anything.
Basically we can use ssrs as local server and as remote server if we are using local then we can easily give path of rdlc inside our project but if we are using remote server setup for ssrs then we need to giver report server url and domain name for authentication.
If we are configuring remote server report then report needs window credential ,so first please check and confirm credential (username and password).
Then you need to confirm that domain name must be same as mentioned in report service url 
http://dqgpsnew/ReportServer here dqgpsnew is domain name so in report server url and domain name for network credential should be the same “dqgpsnew”
if you are requesting it from local host then this is replaced it by ip address dqgpsnew to 13.90.150.102 and report server url like http://13.90.150.102:80/ReportServer
if we donot replace it then it will give “the remote name could not be resolved: 'dqgpsnew'”